# How do large websites like Facebook distribute load?

Tags: scalability

*This may be better suited to Server Fault, but it seems more of a programming challenge to me. I could be wrong.*

I was thinking about how Facebook does what it does. It has over 500 million active users. How do they manage to serve all of those users? Is there one gigantic database holding a record for every single user so that whenever someone on logs in, authentication is checked against that central machine? I'm pretty ignorant about this topic but I can see that a solution like that is simple not scalable. There will come a point where that central server just can't handle everything.

Instead, say that central database is split up into **100** databases so that the load is split across all of them evenly. That must be what Facebook does, but how do they know which user record to store on what machine? Is there a record stored in every single machine and when you log in, a random user machine is used for authentication? That would mean every time someone registers or changes their password, the changes have to be propagated across all **100** servers.

One other solution comes to mind. Maybe they have some way of hashing a user's email address to a specific user database. Then all that would have to be known by the web servers is that hashing algorithm. But this solution brings up its own problem I think. What if you want to add more user database machines? Do you change the hashing algorithm to take into account **101** user databases instead of **100**? Would you start moving user records around so the 101 user databases have the same number of user records? No, that seems ridiculous as well.

Anyways, as you can see I don't know too much about how to solve these problem. Does anyone have some recommended reading about this topic?

Comment: Check out the Facebook engineering blog, http://www.facebook.com/Engineering Somewhere in there they talk about how they had to get away from the traditional relationship model that we're used

Comment: The answers are specific to Facebook.  For another example, Google has multiple copies of the entire search database, so your query can hit any of their database servers.  The search databases are not synchronized.  It depends on what you're trying to do with your website when you distribute the load.

Comment: Oh hey, check this out! Someone asked about Cassandra : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/28992/best-cassandra-learning-resources On our new Programmers StackExchange (Programmers is geared towards "whiteboard"/thinking related questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good starting point might be to take a look at [Cassandra](http://highscalability.com/product-facebooks-cassandra-massive-distributed-store) ([lecture notes](http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/2009/02/07/FacebookCassandraArchitectureAndDesign.aspx)), the distributed database that powers FB's inbox search.

Here's more about [FB's nuts and bolts](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-work-nuts-bolts-technology-explained/).
You might also find some gems in the [FB developer news](http://www.facebook.com/notes.php?id=9445547199).

Comment: Thanks, reading about how Cassandra works has been pretty informative!